# IE 8 reporting error at line 373402504

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

IE 8 is reporting an error ("Expected identifier, string or number) at a line number that is on a distant planet. The code works just fine on FireFox.

When I view source, the generated file is onlu 624 lines long, so line number 373402504 appears to be a rather bogus message. Unfortunately, it is messing up my JavaScript badly.

Comment: kind of hard to troubleshoot without seeing any code

Comment: Link to a page, or show some of the possibly offending JS code

Comment: Ignore the line numbers that IE's error messages feed you. They're notoriously erroneous themselves.

Comment: When IE tells you a huge line number, it means the code was loaded via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the IE Developer toolbar? Although not as great as Firebug (for Firefox), it will enable you to do some debugging on you JS. If I am not wrong, IE8 comes bundled with the developer toolbar and pressing F12 (while in IE) will initiate it. If your IE8 installation does not have it, then you can search for it and install it.

Comment: The toolbar is useless. It cannot find the line in error because it doesn't exist.